# How would one go about creating a mathematical model following this spec?

Tags: mathematical-modeling

A motor insurance company that provides policies covering the costs of car repair resulting from road accidents would like you to build a mathematical model for estimating the probability that the total size of all claims from such policies in 2020 exceed some threshold. The model should take into account recent statistical trends, analysing the number of road accidents during recent years, and the past data for sizes of claims. 
Using data from https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/road-accidents-and-safety-statistics

Comment: Really? This is a whole new level of  'do my homework'.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.